# How do I debug a jump to a bad address?

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb

I am currently debugging some assembly code using GDB and am stuck on the following problem. Somehow or other, I've ended up at a bogus instruction address, probably because either I called a bogus function pointer, or I mangled the return address on the parent stack frame.

GDB is fantastic and stops the program *exactly* when it detects this has happened. However, what it doesn't tell me is the instruction address that *sent* me to this bogus address. So now I am stuck. I know that I am now at a bogus address, but I have no way of knowing how I got here. What I think I need is a list of the last n values that $rip has taken on. But I cannot find any way of doing that in GDB's documentation and am pretty sure it is not possible.

So I would appreciate it if anyone else had any great tips on low-level debugging they could share. Thanks!
  -Patrick

Comment: See `record full` and `reverse-stepi` commands.

Comment: You could also look at the current stack frame and set a breakpoint just before the most recent RIP.

Answer (score 0):

I think GDB's trace might helps

https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Tracepoints.html

Answer (score 0):

When your code crash, the trap is raised and the instruction pointer jump to the trap table, the jump depends on the trap raised.

You want to determine which instruction causes this trap, so you can execute the command [backtrace (bt)](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_42.html) to show the latest exectuted functions before the jump to the trap table. When you identify the function, execute step by step to idenfy the instruction which causes the error.

If you are using a target with gdb in remote mode, you need to give gdb a strong symbol table to allow the awareness of the whole code symbols.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the OP's specific question of how to figure out where you came from after a `jmp` or `ret` to a bogus address.  `bt` can only help with a `call` to a bad address (the bogus function pointer case that the OP says might be the problem).  Jester's comment looks like the only useful suggestion from anyone.